# Factor poblacional -Python

Tags: python

Tengo que crear un diccionario de 5 estados, el total de personas seran 100 persona, como puedo crear la siguiente secuencia:

Para cada persona del E1 (Estado 1) : 2 personas seran creadas del E2 (Estado 2), 4 personas del E3, 5 personas del E4 y 4 personas del E5.

**La secuencia seria de la siguiente manera: 1:2:4:5:4**

```
            Estado    TEL    SEXO............
Persona 1   E1        
            E2
            E2
            E3
            E3
            E3
            E3
            E4
            E4
            E4
            E4
            E4
            E5
            E5
            E5
Persona 16  E5

total de personas en primer iteracion = 16
```

¿Como puedo lograr esa secuencia hasta llegar a 100 personas?

Comment: Sería conveniente que añadieras un ejemplo de código mínimo reproducible para ver cómo has intentando resolver el problema y qué errores te está dando.

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero sería generar una lista con los estados que se generarían en un "ciclo", es decir, en una repetición del patrón 1,2,4,5,4 que indicas. Por ejemplo así:

```
cuantos = [1,2,4,5,4]

ciclo = []
for i, n in enumerate(cuantos, start=1):
  for j in range(n):
    ciclo.append("E{}".format(i))
```

La lista ciclo así generada contiene los valores:

```
['E1', 'E2', 'E2', 'E3', 'E3', 'E3', 'E3', 'E4', 'E4', 'E4', 'E4', 'E4', 'E5', 'E5', 'E5', 'E5']
```

Para seguir a partir de aquí y generar 100 personas, tienes dos vías

### Método particular

El ciclo que acabamos de generar tiene longitud 16. Quieres generar 100 personas, lo que no es múltiplo de 16. El múltiplo más cercano es 96, que es 16*6, por lo que tendrás que completar 6 ciclos, y en el útimo generar 4 personas más. Siguiendo el ciclo dado, las últimas 4 personas serían E1, E2, E2, E4

Así pues, los estados en cuestión podrían generarse así:

```
estados = []
for i in range(6):
  estados.extend(ciclo)
estados.extend(ciclo[:4])
```

### Método general

Para no tener que andar echando cuentas, podemos hacer uso de `itertools.cycle()` que te va proporcionando elementos del iterable que le pases como parámetro, y cuando se termina ese iterable, vuelve a comenzarlo. Usando esta función podríamos parar al haberla invocado 100 veces:

```
import itertools

i = 0
fin = 100
estados = []
for estado in itertools.cycle(ciclo):
  estados.append(estado)
  i+=1
  if i == fin:
    break
```

O más brevemente, usando `next()` y una comprensión de listas:

```
generador = itertools.cycle(ciclo)
estados = [next(generador) for i in range(100)]
```

## Actualización

Si los nombres de los estados no son generados en base al patrón "E1, E2" etc sino unos dados, la cosa sería similar. El ciclo de 16 estados que se repiten se generaría así:

```
cuantos = [1,2,4,5,4]
nombres = ["MTY", "SN", "ESC", "GPE", "APC"]
ciclo = []

for nombre, n in zip(nombres, cuantos):
  for j in range(n):
    ciclo.append(nombre)
```

y el resto sería igual.

**Bonus**

Para los fans de la programación funcional, se puede usar de `itertools` las funciones `repeat()`, `chain()` y `cycle()` para crear un generador que te vaya dando los nombres necesarios, y después hacer `next()` 100 veces (o las que sean) sobre ese generador.

La sintaxis es mucho más oscura y difícil de leer, por lo que particularmente yo no la aconsejo (más difícil de mantener), pero como curiosidad, ahí queda:

```
from itertools import repeat, chain, cycle

cuantos = [1,2,4,5,4]
nombres = ["MTY", "SN", "ESC", "GPE", "APC"]

generador = cycle(chain(*(repeat(nombre, n) for nombre,n in zip(nombres, cuantos))))
estados = [next(generador) for i in range(100)]
```

Comment: Y si en vez de agregar E1, tiene que ser diferente nombre de string, digamos que en estados, deberan de ir los nombres de estados que tengo en una lista, los cuales son 5. [MTY, SN, ESC, GPE, APC]